# Intent to take photo with better resolution?

Tags: android

My app is using this Intent to take photos:
`startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
TAKE_PICTURE);`
But the resolution is really low...

Is there any way to improve the resolution? or I have to create my own Camera Activity?

Comment: The quality is lower than if you take a picture via the camera app?

Comment: Yes, when I take a photo with Camera app the resolution is 5MP but with this intent the resolution is 640*480...

Comment: ya exactly...i am also having 5MP HTC Hero and i have also implemented the above intent but photo is captured with only 640*480

Comment: what about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818245/capturing-picture-storing-into-sdcard/3819029#3819029 , you have already ask a question regarding camera activity, then why didnt you update this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html this is behavior by design.

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to pass some extra data with the intent to specify the size you want.  For example, [EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT) sounds like it might work.  I haven't tried it though.