# capturing picture storing into sdcard

Tags: android

Hi am new to android my requirement is to taking picture and storing it into an sdcard and retriving it as an object. Is there any code? plz help me

Answer (score 2):

You can capture picture using an **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
```

Have a look at the implementation of Camera Capture Example:
http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/